# Ways of writing sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My English is not very good so I hope you understand .

I don't know how to say it in English but we studied that there are 2 ways to write a set.

1. The first way is just to list these {you list the elements here and you separate with commas}
2. The second way is to find a special property that they share.

For example 
If you have this set $\{2,3,.......,9\}$
You would say that the special property is $\{x:1<x<10,x \mathrm{\;belongs\; to\; the\;natural\;numbers}\}$

**Now my Question is**

How can I write the special property for the following sets:

1. $\{3,5,6,9,10,12,15,18,20,21,24\}$
2. $\{17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47\}$
3. $\{1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55\}$

I would be grateful if you help

Comment: The issue is that the property $\varphi(x)$ to be used in the "specification" of the set $A = \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$ "must be" an expression that is simpler than the list of the memebers of the set $A$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i don't understand last thing you say but i did get the idea to solve

Comment: Some hints: For the first, you may not have a single property that describes the elements of the set, but you could say that every element of the set satisfies property $\phi$ or property $\psi$ (or both). See if you can find two such properties for the first. For the second, this is a pretty well known property of numbers (restricted to $17\leq x\leq 47$). For the third, see Mauro's comment.

Comment: Your English is fine. You have correctly described the two ways. But you don't always need to be able to use both. Sometimes just the list is better, along with some words that describe what's going on. For the last example you should tell your reader that these are just the first few Fibonacci numbers, and give the recursive definition if necessary. You could pack all that into the second form, but it wouldn't help your reader.

Comment: @EthanBolker prof ask use to use second way .... you use hard words..

Comment: I think your professor is asking a bad question. I understand that you can't tell him or her that. @NashJ 's answer might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

For case 1, look through the factors of each number.

For case 2, look at the factors of each number (different from case 1, note the definition of prime).

For case three, Google the Fibonacci numbers.

Also, you can have the Set C be union of Set A defined by property p and Set B defined by property q by defining Set C by the property p OR q.

Comment: What factor ? ........

Comment: @user430638 Which case are you talking about?

Comment: you say look for factors what is factors

Comment: @user430638 $1$, $2$, $3$, and $6$ are the factors of $6$. If $a$ divides $b$, then $a$ is a factor of $b$.

Comment: @user430638 a *factor* of an integer $n$ is an integer $k$ such that there exists another integer $l$ where $n=k\cdot l$.  For example the positive factors of $12$ are $1,2,3,4,6,12$.  The positive factors of $16$ are $1,2,4,8,16$.  The positive factors of $7$ are $1,7$

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are as follows:

- 1: $\{ x \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 3} | x = 0 \, \mathrm{mod}\, 3 \, \mathrm{or}\, x = 0 \, \mathrm{mod}\, 5, \, \max(x) = 24 \} -$  [See this](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C5%2C6%2C9%2C10%2C12%2C15%2C18%2C20%2C21%2C24&language=english&go=Search)
- 3: $\{x(n) \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0} | 2\leq n \leq 11, x(n) = x(n - 1) + x(n - 2), x(0) = 0, x(1) = 1\} -$ [See this](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C8%2C13%2C21%2C34%2C55&sort=&language=english&go=Search)

The second series contains prime numbers.

Comment: The sets you currently describe are infinite, but the sets the OP is wishing to describe are finite.  You should put an additional constraint in each as to the maximum (*and minimum*) size of each element.

Comment: Thank you .. i try to past my other sequence in the search in the page you give me but i dont know where is the special property